# How to delete an object using its reference on C++

Tags: c++, oop, object, reference

I have a project specification(so I can't change it) where I've created a function

```
const mat4& GetView() const;
```

The mat4 object is created on this function:

```
mat4* a = new mat4();
mat4 &ret = *a;
return ret;
```

And later on I'll want to delete it. But how can I do it once I've left the GetView method?

Thanks.

Comment: That's pretty terrible design. Much better not to use dynamic allocation at all.

Comment: Any specific reason you're not using a member var as returning a reference to that? Something wickedly-immovable in your constructor?

Comment: Yeah, this seems strange. Does this really need to be allocated and deleted every time this method is called? It seems like this could be a class member that is cleaned up during destruction. Also, I think `return *a;` should suffice, rather than creating the temporary variable.

Comment: Something to think about... if the spec has this function specified, does it also specify that the user will expect to delete the pointer to the data? This is very unusual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the address:

```
const mat4 & x = GetView();
delete &x;
```

(I'm assuming that `operator&` is not overloaded. If it is, you need to do something a bit more complex.)

Comment: Alas I don't have a compiler handy to double check, but I thought `delete` required a non-const pointer.

Comment: Const-ness is confusing. I think this is declaring a const value. I don't think const here says anything about the address. But I may be wrong. For example, `const mat4* const` is different than `const mat4*` and `mat4* const`. I'm not sure how references fit into all of this.

Comment: @Hurkyl: That makes no sense. Constness only affects objects that exist. The existence of objects itself (i.e. creation and destruction) is conceptually *outside* of that. Imagine you want to delete elements from a `std::set` -- but the elements are const, aren't they? And what if you have a const local variable in a function -- that function could never return?! And objects with const members could never be destroyed.

Comment: Conceptually, one should not be able to mutate an object through a const pointer: and deleting the object is the most severe mutation of all! But I remembered I have visual studio on this computer so I just tested it, and `delete` does work on `const` pointers. Weird. `free` requires a non-const pointer, though.

Comment: @Hurkyl you should probably read this: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html We aren't talking about const pointers here. We are talking about pointers to constant data.

Comment: @Geoff: That is what "const pointer" means, in the terminology I'm familiar with. `const int*` is a const pointer. `int *const` is a pointer constant.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Deleting an object is *not* a mutation, just like creating an object isn't. Otherwise `T const x;` would be illegal!

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect there are only three reasonable options here:

- You misread the spec, and `GetView` isn't supposed to return `const mat4&`
- You misread the spec, and `GetView` is supposed to return a reference to an existing object rather than a newly created one
- The project specification is seriously flawed, and it really is worth pushing the matter.

Of course, on that last point, you really should gather up as much rationale as you can before you start pushing.